# How to load "child.vue" into the proper "parent.vue" position

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm writing a single page web app with vue. It has 4 "page.vue"'s  and in either of those goes a right and left child .vue component.

for example Page1.vue looks like this (I left style and script to keep it short)

Page1Links & Page1Rechts are the child VUEs that I try to load into the main part

(2 seperate componets were used because one needs to be changed for a more complex one soon and it's written so that the other component can stay as is)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
      <div class="page-container">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1 id="page-h1"><span>Mauderer</span> Containertreppenkonfigurator</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="page-main-content">
          <Page1Links id="links"/>
          <Page1Rechts id="rechts"/>
        </div>
        <div class="page-footer">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

WHAT I WANNA SEE is a header component spanning the whole page width

below that the 2 child components next to each other spanning full width
(70% left comp 30% right comp)

(wrapped in some nice design to make it clear they belong together for e.g. I tried a box shadow arround the page-main-content class, which is not showing another indicator that how I tried it won't work, or rather the main div is simply empty)

and below that the footer full width

WHAT I GET is all divs below each other at the top of the page:
1. header div
2. main div(which appears empty)
3. footer div

and below that the two child.vue, they are next to each other but that is only because I forced them too inside them.

EDIT:
Ok thanks for the info with flex you two that is helpfull in pulling the layout out of the child components.
To clarify:
My problem is that my child components are not rendered inside the main div where their tag is.
That div class="page-main-content" is empty and the Page1Links and Page1Rechts are rendered below the footer.
And I thought from the little vue experience that I have, a .vue component is rendered to where you put it's tag but that does not work here, and I don't know why.

[problem example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzeH3.png)

In this pic you can see the problem:
the page parent vue and all its divs are rendered in the top(2nd grey bar is the footer) and even though I expected my approach to render the children into that main part they are actually rendered after the page 1 so basically below it.

I have bootstrapvue included I just thought it would be simpler this way, if I'm wrong please tell me

Comment: dude what i came to know from this question is that you want 1 div on top having full width and below that two comp (one with 70 and other with 30 width). If you want you can use flex to achieve it or use bootstrap and you can be more precise to actually get a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But where is your css code?

I do not know if i understand it right, but if you want to #links and #rechts next to each other you can make it by flex for example.

```
.page-main-content{display: flex;}
#links{flex: 0 0 70%;}
#rechts{flex: 0 0 30%;}
```

Comment: I left the css out to safe space

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple of times before it worked and it actually solved it, I don't really understand why though? The flex now pushed the children inside the page1 into the page-main-content.

I do understand that this is way more handy than what I did (code the size of the component into itself) but the components were next to each ohter before so what the flex did is force the children to render inside the parent instead of below/after it.

So thanks, problem solved.

If sbd. knows a short answer, I'm still interested into why that is though.